# Can't get for loop to print correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google script to create endnotes from footnotes in a document. Everything is working except for replacing the superscript after the footnote has been removed. Specifically, I can't get a for loop to start counting at 1 instead of zero.

The bit of script is:

```
function replaceNotes() {
  var par = body.getParagraphs();
  var notes = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes();

  for(var i in notes){
    notes[i].getParent().editAsText().appendText(i);
    return;
  }
}
```

This works, but it starts printing at 0, which is expected. So, I set my loop to `for(var i = 1; i < notes; i++)...` and it doesn't print a value anymore when run. Looking at the documentation, I don't see any reason why the script wouldn't work. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the length of notes with notes.length

```
  function replaceNotes() {
      var par = body.getParagraphs();
      var notes = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFootnotes();

      for(var i = i; i < notes.length; i++){
        notes[i].getParent().editAsText().appendText(i);
        return;
      }
    }
```